# Unable to access node server created on windows machine on other devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, server, localhost

I am building a web app using Node and express.  On my PC, I run the app by typing `node app.js` which gets the server running on `http://localhost:1008/`

On my android phone, which is connected to the **same** network, I typed
`http://<ipv4 address>:1008/`   but it doesn't work.
The wifi network is set to private(home) and i tried turning off firewall, but still it doesn't work
I am using Windows 7 PC.

My app (just a test app)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine','ejs')

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render('home')
})

app.get("/about",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("about")
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{console.log("server running on port 3000"})
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you using any antivirus?

Comment: Please share your code that listens for the connection.

Comment: @TomBoutell Updated with code (my code is just a simple nodejs test application)

Comment: okay, my theory was that you were specifically listening on a particular host address. You are not, so this should work, unless something at the OS level is blocking it. So I agree with those who hold the theory that it's a firewall issue. or else you are not using the right local IP address and you're trying to use the public IP that you see if you ask Google for your IP.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities that you are not able to access your node server on other devices,

1. You might have installed antivirus on your machine, which is protecting your firewall. So, it is not allowing to access the port on which your application server is running.
2. Your windows defender is not allowing you to access port outside your host machine.

Solution for above problems is,

1. If you have antivirus, then you need to allow port from antivirus firewall setting
2. If port access is denied by windows defender/firewall, then you need to allow port from windows firewall